# How to insert new item in empty array any position?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swift3

i have a table that is multiple selected allow. first time user select some row . second time user come beck this page deselect some row and may be selected some row or not . but i need to hold previous selected rows . that row indicated price . so i need to track price that is the reason  table view selected row i am tracking .

Here i my declaration array empty :

```
 var groupSelectedOldPrice : [String] = []
```

here is my table row selected index item price append to the array:

```
 if  addon?.isSelect == true {
     cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
      groupSelectedOldPrice[indexPath.row] = (addon?.price)! // Index out of range
 }
```

when user press done button :

```
        let selectedUserRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows

        if let _selectedUserRows = selectedUserRows  {

            for select in _selectedUserRows {
              print(select.row)
              let dishprice =  Double((dish?.price)!)! - Double(groupSelectedOldPrice[select.row])!
              dish?.price = "\(dishprice)"
         }
      }
```

i am not sure How  i can achieved this . should I use dictionary for  `key value`

Comment: Basically you cannot insert items with index subscription. You have to use `append` or `insert`. Besides I recommend to use a custom struct as model with a `isSelected` property.

Comment: @vadian would you give an example to `struct` like solution please?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper The comments are the wrong place to answer continuative questions. Please ask a new one.

Comment: ok vadian if i asked i will send you the link ....

Comment: I have this question too!  Why can't I give a length to an array and then put items in where and when I want.  Java does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting **Array index is out of range** error because you are trying to insert at ***discrete*** indexes (more like *skipping* intermediate indexes. But it doesn't work this way. You just can't have an array like `["a", "b", _ , _ , "g", "u", _ , _ , "y"]`)

Let's do one thing. You maintain a `counter` var, insert at that `counter`'s position and then increment that counter. Something like:

```
var counter: Int = 0
...
groupSelectedOldPrice.insert("your string" at:counter)
counter = counter +1
...
```

**EDIT**

(Answered according to what you asked for)

To achieve your requirement, you can maintain a `Dictionary`. A `Dictionary` where `key` will be your `indexpath.row` and `value` will be your `String`. Pretty much like:

```
var dic: [Int:String] = [:] // it's your declaration
....
....
dic[indexpath.row] = "your string" // when you try to fill your dictionary
```

Comment: i want to figure out how can i archived this yourArray.insert("Your String", at: 7) . where array is empty  . is there any alternative .

Comment: See my recent edit. No it's not possible. You just can't skip 3rd or 6th or whatever indexes when inserting to the `nth` index.

Comment: do you know any alternative to achieved my goal . according to my question

Comment: `Dictionary` will be a good match for your case but not best. You should use custom struct instead as @vadian suggested in a comment.

Comment: why not best  Dictionary ?

Comment: It's an other question and out of this scope. For now, just consider that `struct` will be more manageable than `Dictionary` for this particular case.

Comment: at least if you give me hints or link to learn why not best Dictionary?  i will accept your answer and up-voted .

Comment: Well okay. `Dictionary` isn't best because every time you have to add item to your dictionary and when you need them you have to iterate through all your keys. But if you just use a custom struct with an `isSelected` property what you will set to `true` or `false` then you can just search for `true` or `false` members.

Comment: i don't think it measuring  not best Dictionary . however thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can insert your element at a specific index of array

```
let index = 1
yourArray.insert("Your String", at: index)
```

Comment: @vadian is it work `yourArray.insert("Your String", at: 7)` ? where array is empty . cause i am not sure which one user select

Comment: No it does not. It works always if the index <=  the number of items in the array.

Comment: @NazmulHasan Since you're using `UITableView` why don't you use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get all selected rows?